# BigQuery UPDATE of column within nest from GoogleAnalytics export

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have a website's Google Analytics tracking data exported in BigQuery to a `ga_session_*` table. It's the standard setup of any GA export to BQ I've come across.
For simplicity's sake I'll refer to only `ga_session_20220801`.

This table has the following fields:

```
 - visitorId    INTEGER NULLABLE            
 - visitNumber  INTEGER NULLABLE            
 - visitId  INTEGER NULLABLE            
 - visitStartTime   INTEGER NULLABLE            
 - date STRING  NULLABLE            
 - totals   RECORD  NULLABLE            
 - trafficSource    RECORD  NULLABLE            
 - device   RECORD  NULLABLE            
 - geoNetwork   RECORD  NULLABLE            
 - customDimensions RECORD  REPEATED            
 - hits RECORD  REPEATED        
 - fullVisitorId    STRING  NULLABLE            
 - userId   STRING  NULLABLE            
 - clientId STRING  NULLABLE            
 - channelGrouping  STRING  NULLABLE            
 - socialEngagementType STRING  NULLABLE            
 - privacyInfo  RECORD  NULLABLE
```

Field `hits` is a **repeated** field i.e. it contains multiple records for each table record.

### My question

How can I execute an update statements on field `hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId`, where `sourcePropertyInfo` is another nest inside `hits` (but not a repeated record)?

### My attempts

```
update `my_project.my_dataset.ga_sessions_20220801`
set hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId = 'some value'
where 1=1

Cannot access field sourcePropertyInfo on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [2:10]
```

```
update `my_project.my_dataset.ga_sessions_20220801`
set (select sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName from unnest(hits)) = 'some value'
where 1=1

Syntax error: Expected keyword DELETE or keyword INSERT or keyword UPDATE but got keyword SELECT at [2:6]
```

The following is my only attempt that was not stopped by syntax. I ended up trying to re-create the whole nest by listing each field. But still returns an error at runtime due to the record being repeated.

```
update `my_project.my_dataset.ga_sessions_20220801`
set hits = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      hits.hitNumber, hits.time, hits.hour, hits.minute, hits.isSecure, hits.isInteraction, hits.isEntrance, hits.isExit, hits.referer, hits.page,
      (SELECT AS STRUCT hits.transaction.transactionId, hits.transaction.transactionRevenue, hits.transaction.transactionTax, hits.transaction.transactionShipping, hits.transaction.affiliation,
      hits.transaction.currencyCode,
      hits.transaction.localTransactionRevenue, hits.transaction.localTransactionTax, hits.transaction.localTransactionShipping, hits.transaction.transactionCoupon)
      as transaction,
      hits.item, hits.contentInfo, hits.appInfo, hits.exceptionInfo, hits.eventInfo, hits.product, hits.promotion, hits.promotionActionInfo, hits.refund, hits.eCommerceAction, hits.experiment, hits.publisher, hits.customVariables, hits.customDimensions, hits.customMetrics, hits.type, hits.social, hits.latencyTracking,
      (SELECT AS STRUCT 'some value' as sourcePropertyDisplayName, hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId)
      as sourcePropertyInfo,
      hits.contentGroup, hits.dataSource, hits.publisher_infos, hits.uses_transient_token
    FROM gas.hits
  )
where 1=1

Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're so close with the third query. You should recreate the hits column, but by preserving the original data structure.

In the query below, I get all the hit rows and replace their sourcePropertyInfo key in the struct.
Then, since I unnested the hits, to gather it again, I used array_agg so it becomes an array again.

```
update `my_project.my_dataset.ga_sessions_20220801`
set hits = 
  (
    select array_agg(t)
    from (
      select
        hit.* replace(
          struct(
            hit.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName,
            'some value' as sourcePropertyTrackingId
          ) as sourcePropertyInfo
        )
    from unnest(hits) as hit
    ) as t
  )
where true
```

Comment: amazing! Big thanks! I did not know you could use REPLACE like that